# Migrate wp 8.1 uwp project to win 10 UWP project already in store

Tags: migration, win-universal-app, uwp, project.json

I started a new win 10 UWP and thought that I could just link it to the same app already in the store. But Visual Studio 2015 told me it couldn't be done when it listed all the apps in the store. I had to tick the checkbox to even see the package I wanted it to link to.

So I [read all these things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx#PackageManifest) with unload project. edit csproj file and package manifest and have 122 build errors when I open the new project.json
when I open the old csproj I get 417 errors.

old csproj:
[image]

new project.json:
[image]

**Can't I just start over with a new win10 UWP and link it to an existing store app?**

Comment: You can have both a windows 10 and windows 8.1 version of your app in the store

Comment: and are they linked by some id?

Comment: @JPHellemons Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a windows 8.1 universal application that I needed to port to UWP later. What I did is to create a new project and ported the code manually.

I made the application name same as the one already on the store. After I completed the app,

Note:[Optional] Don't forget to change device family name to Mobile and Desktop only in package manifest if you aren't planning/tested for other families.

1. Associate the app-> Right click on project in Visual studio -> Store -> Associate the with the store -> Choose already reserved app names -> select your win8.1 app. This will add the publisher info and update package Id and other data.
2. Changed the version number to be higher than the already published Win8.1 app on store. So that I can publish updates to the 8.1 version later if needed.

> Note  The version number of your Windows 10 packages must be higher than those for any Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and/or Windows Phone 8.1 packages you are publishing
>
> Important  Once a customer on Windows 10 gets your UWP package, you won't be able to roll that customer back to using a package for any previous OS version. Make sure you have thoroughly tested your UWP packages on Windows 10 before adding them to your submission.

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188601.aspx#windows_10) about adding Windows 10 to a previously-published app and [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188602.aspx) for package version info.

3. Create app packages for publishing to store, Run Local tests.
4. Login to dashboard, locate your application and then create a new submission, add the new UWP package. Don't remove the Win8.1 packages if you want them to be still published.
5. Add screenshots and promotion Images(optional) and submit.